# HTML5 Cache Manifest Not uploading

Tags: html, offline

I am working on an offline application in HTML and am having a problem using the HTML5 manifest. I am able to get it to download all the files and the manifest but when I change the manifest it does not do an update.

I see a record of the browser downloading the manifest in the web server log, and it does issue a bunch of progress events. However there is no record in the web server log of it downloading any of the files listed in the manifest nor do any changes show up in the browser.

This is with firefox 3.6.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest itself is still subject to normal browser caching rules, make sure you serve the manifest files with an expiry header set to immediate.  You can do this on Apache in .htaccess with this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires. c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest “access plus 0 seconds”
</IfModule>
```

In the short term, try hitting Ctrl+F5 to force a full reload or clearing your browser cache.